# jaxb inheritance custom mapping

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

I have those classes

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Root{
    @element
    public B element = new B(); 
}

public abstract class A {

}
public class B extends A{
    @XmlElement
    String param1;
    @XmlElement
    String param2;
    public B(){
        param1 = "0";
        param2 = "102";
    }
}
```

They both belong to a root element and I want to create this XML:

```
<root>
    <A>
        <B>
            <param1>0</param1>
            <param2>102</param2>
        </B>
    </A>
</root>
```

It is possible to do that or I will have to create a `List` (one element list) and than use
`@XmlWrapperElement` annotation?

As requested I will past the real src code, but it is a little big.
This is what jaxb generated: 
http://pastebin.com/Nccnv52W

The problem is that my xsd looks like 
http://pastebin.com/mpdMs2zF

as you can see, it is a choice element so I cant have something like this  http://pastebin.com/VBQaSft5
otherwise I will have validation problems unmarshaling the XMLs

Comment: In class model you use inheritance between A and B classes. But your xml suggests to use composition instead of inheritance. Can you change your classes and use composition?

Comment: I can, the problem is that I have a lot of classes, C D E etc.. and they all extends A
I cant have properties C and D for example in my xml, they are mutual exclusive

Comment: By the way, checked what jaxb autogenerated based on the xsd schema, and it did a composition as @mykhaylo sugested, the problem is that as I told you, only one can be used
I cant have a XML like this one
`<root>  
    <A>  
        <B>  
            <param1>0</param1>  
            <param2>102</param2>  
        </B>  
        <C>  
            <param1>0</param1>  
            <param2>102</param2>  
        </C>  
    </A>  
</root>`  
and the composition allows that

Comment: Could you improve your source code in question? Now you declare param1 property but you use orig variable. Could you improve your example also? I need more information for better understanding your problem.

Comment: well, I will past the real src code, but it is a little big
this is what jaxb generated
http://pastebin.com/Nccnv52W
the problem is that my xsd is like that
http://pastebin.com/mpdMs2zF
as you can see, it is a choice element so I cant have something like this
http://pastebin.com/VBQaSft5
otherwise I will have validation problems unmarshaling the XMLs